# SOAP, WSDL and Arrays/List

Tags: arrays, web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

I seems to have a problem defining arrays in wsdl, and using them... here is some snippings, to help me show the problem - any input would be very welcome - thanks in advance..

```
<xs:complexType name="Test3ResponseItem">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="FullName" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string" nillable="false" />
    <xs:element name="Mode" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string" nillable="false" />
    <xs:element name="CreationTime" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string" nillable="false" />
    <xs:element name="LastAccessTime" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string" nillable="false" />
    <xs:element name="LastWriteTime" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string" nillable="false" />
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Test3ResponseArray">
<xs:complexContent mixed="false">
    <xs:restriction base="soapenc:Array">
        <xs:attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="tns:Test3ResponseItem[]" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="Test3Response">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Items" minOccurs="0" type="tns:Test3ResponseArray" nillable="false" />
        <xs:element name="hasErrors" minOccurs="0" type="xs:boolean" nillable="true" />
        <xs:element name="hasWarnings" minOccurs="0" type="xs:boolean" nillable="true" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

And then invoking the web service with this soap request

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
  <Test3Response xmlns="http://powershell.dsv.com/powershell/">
     <a:items xmlns:a="http://powershell.dsv.com/powershell/">
        <Test3ResponseItem>
        <Test3ResponseItem>
           <FullName>C:\temp\FMS</FullName>
           <Mode>d----</Mode>
           <CreationTime>9/15/2017 10:37:21 AM</CreationTime>
           <LastAccessTime>9/15/2017 10:59:49 AM</LastAccessTime>
           <LastWriteTime>9/15/2017 10:59:49 AM</LastWriteTime>
        </Test3ResponseItem>
           <FullName>C:\temp\FTP Setup</FullName>
           <Mode>d----</Mode>
           <CreationTime>2/1/2017 10:07:17 AM</CreationTime>
           <LastAccessTime>3/10/2017 3:17:22 PM</LastAccessTime>
           <LastWriteTime>3/10/2017 3:17:22 PM</LastWriteTime>
        </Test3ResponseItem>
     </a:items>
     <hasErrors>false</hasErrors>
     <hasWarnings>false</hasWarnings>
  </Test3Response>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Im getting something like this in SoapUI Schema Compliance:
Element not allowed: Test3ResponseItem@http.... in element Items@http......

How else do i return a list of items - is my wsdl not specifing an array?

im trying to define a wsdl and a response for something like this:

The thing im trying to do is something like like:

```
Public Class Test3ResponseItem
    Public Property Fullname as string
    Public Property Mode as string
    Public Property CreationTime as string
    Public Property LastAccessTime as string
    Public Property LastWriteTime as string
End Class

Public Class Test3Response
    Public Property Items As List(Of Test3ResponseItem)
    Public Property hasWarnings as bool
    Public Property hasErrors as bool
End Class
```

Complete wsdl is available via [filedropper](http://www.filedropper.com/powershell_5)

Comment: Please note that your XSD contains errors. The first Test3ResponseItem is empty, without mandatory elements. Secondly, just behind the second Test3ResponseItem, the FullName element is present instead of opening a complex element Test3ResponseItem. Next, the Items element starts with uppercase, whereas your sample XML contains items with lowercase. Please fix these errors and try again.

Comment: I never use soapenc:Array definition. In your case I would simply define Test3ResponseArray as a sequence of Test3ResponseItem (having maxOccurs="unbounded").

Comment: Still no luck - sadly.
The 1st Test3ResposeItem that was empty, was a copy past error.

      <Test3Response xmlns="http://powershell.dsv.com/PSHost/powershell/">
         <a:Items xmlns:a="http://powershell.dsv.com/PSHost/powershell/">
            <Test3ResponseItem>
               <FullName>filename</FullName>
               <Mode>-a---</Mode>
               <CreationTime></CreationTime>
               <LastAccessTime></LastAccessTime>
               <LastWriteTime></LastWriteTime>
            </Test3ResponseItem>

Could you show me a mockup of what the reponce should look like?

Comment: Can you attach your WSDL to your question?

Comment: Link to complete wsdl have been added at the bottom - thanks

Comment: Link changed to filedropper as it seems shareing from googledocs require authentication